# How should I implement my lambda handler with my REST API gateway model using non- proxy lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am stuck on how I should begin my lambda handler that will read some data from dynamodb. I have defined my api gateway model with the requests and response models, therefore do I need to state any  status codes in the lambda handler ? Do I use API gateway proxy response event ? Any code examples
in Java would be helpful.

My notes on what I should include in the lambda handler:

- access DB
- map over table
- Find attribute
- Return response to api ?

What am I missing ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you decided to use a non-proxy Lambda integration then you need to define an integration response using a regex. Here is an example using nodeJS:

[lambda regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC2JG.png)

Normally i declare my error messages just like this:

```
const errorMessages = {
    INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: {
        message: "Internal server error!",
        code: 500
    },
    ERROR_BODY_INVALID: {
        message: "Invalid request body",
        code: 400
    }
};
```

Then throw an error like this

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
   try {
      // do something                   
   } catch (error) { 
        callback(JSON.stringify(errorMessages.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
   };
}
```

When a lambda error regex matches then it's mapped to the configured response status code.

P.D. If you are using Java this method does not work and you need to use proxy integration